# Equality on ratio of infimum of measures

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X)$ be a measurable space, let $p$ and $q$ be two probability measures on $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X)$ and let $f:\mathcal X\to[0,\infty[$ be a measurable function such that $q(f)$ and $p(f)$ are finite and $f>0$ $q$-almost surely.
I want to show the following equality (or determine under which aditional assumption it is true)
\begin{align*}
\inf_{\substack{B\in\Sigma_X:\\q(1_B \cdot f)>0}} \frac{p(1_B\cdot f)}{q(1_B\cdot f)}=\inf_{\substack{B\in \Sigma_X:\\q(B)>0}}\frac{p(B)}{q(B)}
\end{align*}
I'm not even sure how to start with this one.

Comment: Say $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Setting $p=\chi_{[0,1]}\lambda$, $q=\frac12\chi_{-1,1]}\lambda$, $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ gives a counterexample. (I suspect maybe it's true if you assume$f>0$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I guess $f>0$ $q$-surely might be enough to remove your counter example.

Comment: well of course null sets don't matter...

Comment: Yes my question is more about the fact that we may not need $f>0$ $p$-surely.

Comment: saying null sets don't matter _says_ that it's true for $f>0$ if and only if it's true for $f>0$ almost surely.